# What's the simplest way to make a git push on a branch automatically deploy to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I want to be able to make a commit to my repo via GitHub WebUI, and have a webhook start a `eb deploy` process of the new `HEAD` commit automatically.

I understand there are tools for this (CodePipeline/CodeDeploy), but it isn't clear if those tools work with Elastic Beanstalk. Using such a comprehensive solution for such a simple problem also seems like over-engineering (read: unnecessary overhead). Surely there is a simpler way.

**Background:**
The app I'm working on outgrew its shared host environment, so I moved it to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. Previously I was auto-deploying updates on a shared host with a simple PHP script. When I would `git push`, the webhook would hit that script via HTTP, and the script would run a `git pull origin mybranch`, which would retrieve any updated files.

Right now I can log into a Cloud9 IDE to `git pull && eb deploy` code updates, but this isn't an ideal solution if I want to let other developers deploy changes.

I tried re-implementing that old solution on Elastic Beanstalk, but the ephemeral nature of EC2 instances means I can't save a SSH keypair or known_hosts on there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the EB integration with Git,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html

And this question might be more suited for Stackoverflow, with the same tag.

Comment: I'm already using that eb CLI to `git pull && eb deploy`. Unfortunately, it lacks the commit hook integration I'm talking about: it requires using the AWS CLI to actually deploy the changes to the environment. That has to be run from *somewhere*, so it it would require maintaining a secondary "deploy" server.
I didn't think this fit with StackOverflow since it's about code deployment and not programming. I'd posted this here after reading this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141944/286262 That answer was from 2012 though, so maybe times have changed..?